# Having trouble understanding how this piece of code works "binaryString[i] = ((number & 1) + '0')"

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

It's material from a lecture slide, but I can't seem to grasp how this section:

```
binaryString[i] = ((number & 1) + '0')
```

is checking whether each bit is 1/0.

Here's the whole block.

```
char *intToBinary(unsigned int number) { 
     char *binaryString = malloc(32+1); 
     int i;
     binaryString[32] = '\0';
     for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
         binaryString[i] = ((number & 1) + '0');
         number = number >> 1;
     }
     return binaryString;
}
```

Comment: It compares the right bit by anding with 1, and stores the value in the array. Then it shifts the bits in number right by 1 position, for the next pass thru the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break `binaryString[i] = ((number & 1) + '0')` down, piece by piece:

first, we'll look at `(number & 1)`. This checks if the least significant bit in `number` is a 1 or not. If it is, this expression evaluates to 1, otherwise it evaluates to 0.

`((number & 1) + '0')` takes the result of this previous calculation and adds it to `0`. If the least significant digit of `number` is `0`, we  add `'0'` and `0`, getting `'0'`. Otherwise, we add `1` and `'0'`, getting `'1'`. This works because in C, characters are a numeric type, so you can add them; the character after `'0'` is `'1'`, so adding `1` to `'0'` gives `'1'`.

We then store this result (either `'1'` or `'0'`) in our string.

Finally, we shift `number` right by one, getting rid of the bit we just looked at: `number = number >> 1;`.

Comment: oh! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)

Comment: Why `'0' + 1` yields `'1'` should be explained.

Comment: @EricPostpischil whoops, typo on my part. And added some explanation.

Comment: @AliceChen if it helped you, feel free to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Important side note: This only works because it is guaranteed that the characters for digits `'0' .. '9'` are in a consecutive range of numbers. For letters `'a' .. 'z'` this is **not** guaranteed. You could have gaps in between. (But in most implementations there are no gaps)

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, but I didn't want to complicate the answer any more by adding details like that, since OP is clearly not very familiar with C at this point

Answer (score 0):

This `(number & 1)` will return 1 for numbers where the right most bit is one, and 0 otherwise. `& 1` works by *anding* all bits, except the right most one, to 0, because 1 is like `00000001` in binary.

So

```
XXXXXXXY
00000001 &
0000000?
```

which is like 1 if `Y` is 1 or 0 if `Y` is 0.

After this comes the `+ '0'`. This is a dirty trick, but is easy to understand when you get the ASCII table. The values of `'0'` is 48 (decimal) in the ASCII table and `'1'` is 49. So `((number & 1) + '0')` would something like `(0 + '0')` which is `'0'` or `(1 + '0')` which is `'1'`. In short, this is here he is filling the `binaryString` with ones and zeros characters.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now.

Comment: In C, `'0' + 1` yields `'1'` even if ASCII is not used.